batchSize in host.json ignored locally
I'm setting a batchSize of 1 in host.json, but when I run the function locally (QueueTrigger input), I get many messages from my queue when it should be only 1.
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  }
}

Even in the console window logs it says "BatchSize": 1.
Why is this setting being ignored? As far as I understand, it should apply locally and when deployed.
When I delete the host.json settings and override the batchSize value in local.settings.json then it works:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={MyDevAccount};AccountKey={MyAccKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__batchSize": 1
  }
}


Now I only get 1 message even though my storage queue has many messages.
But when I define batchSize in host.json again, it even ignores the override in local.settings.json.
Is this a bug, or what am I missing? What if I want to customize my batchSize for the cloud, but keep it 1 locally?

Did you try anything else?

@RithwikBojja No, I gave up because no time and lots of work. Why would you ask that?

I think the problem in your first host.json is that you've specified newBatchThreshold. This means that the parallel batching is actually 1+8 = 9. More info in the source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/48e089c553c2f53b281592a301f854f7bf2b213e/sdk/storage/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common/src/Shared/Queues/QueuesOptions.cs#L27

@AndrewB Thank you Andrew! You were right... I had to also set newBatchThreshold to 0 (or just remove it completely). If you'd like to answer the question, I can mark it as the answer :)

Thanks @ShahinDohan - pleased it worked for you!

Quick answer
Remove the newBatchThreshold from your host.json.
Parallelisation for queue triggers in a given instance is a combination of batchSize and newBatchThreshold together.
You'll notice that you haven't got that setting in your local.settings.json which explains the difference in behaviour.
More information
The logic is more complex than just the batch size. Instead, it looks for if the queue processor is about to run out of messages, and then fetches another batch of messages. There's more info in the source code^1 which has this comment:

The job keeps requesting messages in batches of BatchSize size until number of messages currently being processed is above NewBatchThreshold

So in your host.json example, which has newBatchThreshold as 8, it will make quick retrievals of 1 message - so effectively fetching up to 8 messages, which is probably what you're observing.
Default value of newBatchThreshold
Looking at the source again^1, the default implementation if you don't specify newBatchThreshold explicitly is:
return (_batchSize / 2) * _processorCount;

If your batch size is 1, therefore 1/2 in integer maths, I figure the result will be zero. So it won't fetch more messages and will behave as you originally expected. This is why your local.settings.json did what you expected.
Further thoughts: processing 1 message at a time
This doesn't relate to your question specifically, but just to note that batch size of 1 (even disregarding the new batch threshold) must never be relied upon for processing 1 message at a time. One major reason for this is that the batch size only applies to a single instance of the application. You'll need some other concurrency controls. In your case, I think you are only using a batch size of 1 for local debugging, so I guess you're not worried about this.


batchSize in host.json ignored locally

When you are running in local, it takes values from local.setting.json that is why it will only work with that:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__batchSize": 1
  }
}

Thanks @Andrew and I do agree that one needs to keep newBatchThreshold as 0 or totally remove it for avoiding parallel processing of batch.

What if I want to customize my batchSize for the cloud, but keep it 1 locally

Alternatively, you can add in Environment variable section( same as local.setting.json locally):

You can customize the value by changing the above value.
